# Ng Bootstrap date range picker [markDisabled] doesn't work on input

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to disable certain dates on  [ng bootstrap range picker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview)

Currently, I have a range picker inside a pop-up, and I am using [markDisabled] to disable certain dates.

HTML

```
<form class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
  <input
     #myRangeInput
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy - mm/dd/yyyy"
    name="dp" 
    [(ngModel)]="model" 
    ngbDatepicker 
    [dayTemplate]="t"
    [autoClose]="false"
    [displayMonths]="2"
    [maxDate]="maxDate"
    [minDate]="minDate"
    #d="ngbDatepicker" [markDisabled]="isDisabled">

    <ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused" >
        <span class="custom-day" 
            [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
            [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
            (click)="onDateSelection(date)"
            (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
            (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null"
            >
        {{ date.day }}
        </span>
    </ng-template>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"> click
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Component:

```
 const now = new Date();
 const equals = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
 one && two && two.year === one.year && two.month === one.month && two.day 
 === one.day;

 const before = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
 !one || !two ? false : one.year === two.year ? one.month === two.month ? 
 one.day === two.day
 ? false : one.day < two.day : one.month < two.month : one.year < two.year;

 const after = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
 !one || !two ? false : one.year === two.year ? one.month === two.month ? one.day === two.day
? false : one.day > two.day : one.month > two.month : one.year > two.year;



 export class NgbdDatepickerRange implements OnInit{
 isDisabled = (date: NgbDate, current: {month: number}) => date.day === 13;

startDate: NgbDateStruct;
maxDate: NgbDateStruct;
minDate: NgbDateStruct;
hoveredDate: NgbDateStruct;
fromDate: any;
toDate: any;
model: any;
private _subscription: Subscription;
private _selectSubscription: Subscription;
@ViewChild("d") input: NgbInputDatepicker;
@ViewChild(NgModel) datePick: NgModel;
@ViewChild('myRangeInput') myRangeInput: ElementRef;

isHovered = date => 
this.fromDate && !this.toDate && this.hoveredDate && after(date, this.fromDate) && before(date, this.hoveredDate)
isInside = date => after(date, this.fromDate) && before(date, this.toDate);
isFrom = date => equals(date, this.fromDate);
isTo = date => equals(date, this.toDate);
constructor(element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private _parserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter) {

}
ngOnInit() {
    this.startDate = {year: now.getFullYear(), month: now.getMonth() + 1, day: now.getDate()};
    this.maxDate = { year: now.getFullYear() + 1, month: now.getMonth() + 1, day: now.getDate()};
    this.minDate = {year: now.getFullYear() - 1, month: now.getMonth() + 1, day: now.getDate()};
}

onDateSelection(date: NgbDateStruct) {
    let parsed = '';
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
        this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && after(date, this.fromDate)) {
        this.toDate = date;
        // this.model = `${this.fromDate.year} - ${this.toDate.year}`;
        this.input.close();
    } else {
        this.toDate = null;
        this.fromDate = date;
    }
    if(this.fromDate) {
      parsed += this._parserFormatter.format(this.fromDate);
    }
    if(this.toDate) {
      parsed += ' - ' + this._parserFormatter.format(this.toDate);
    }

    this.renderer.setProperty(this.myRangeInput.nativeElement, 'value', parsed);
}
}
```

[markDisabled] works fine when used as following

```
 <ngb-datepicker #dp (select)="onDateSelection($event)" [displayMonths]="2" 
 [dayTemplate]="t" outsideDays="hidden" [markDisabled]="isDisabled">
```

I would like to use markdisabled property inside input element since I want range picker as a pop up.

Here's the [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdv9a2?file=app%2Fdatepicker-range.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why, but somehow, your custom Day Template (`ng-template let-date="date"`) seem to have prevented the disabled dates from being rendered/marked as disabled on the popout calender. You might have overwritten some properties by accident.

I haven't had an in-depth look at your code, but I have tried the following and it seems to work.

First, on your component.html, I have made use of the `disabled` property which is part of the [DayTemplateContext](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#DayTemplateContext). After which I set the `text-muted` class as true, for `disabled` dates. This will give the greyed out appearance for `disabled` dates. Do make sure that your

```
<ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused" let-disabled="disabled">
  <span class="custom-day" 
  [class.text-muted]="disabled"
  [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
  [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
  (click)="onDateSelection(date)"
  (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
  (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

On your component.ts, I have made the following changes to your `onDateSelection()` method. This is not very elegant, but it does the job for now. I have basically wrapped it with an if-statement to check if the date is on the 13th (which is the disabled date). This will prevent the date itself from being selected.

```
onDateSelection(date: NgbDateStruct) {
  let parsed = '';
  if (date.day!==13) {
   .
   .
   // rest of your code
   }
}
```

EDITED: Thanks @Eliseo for the tips, and yes, we can simply add check for `disabled` on the click event. This way, there is no need for that if-statement on your onDateSelection() statement. I have updated the demo to reflect the changes.

```
<ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused" let-disabled="disabled">
  <span class="custom-day" 
  [class.text-muted]="disabled"
  [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
  [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
  (click)="!disabled && onDateSelection(date)"
  (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
  (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

You may refer to my demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdv9a2-rr33zf?file=app/datepicker-range.ts)

Comment: is more "elegant" `(click)="!disabled && onDateSelection(date)"`

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo for the tips :)